# Eloquent variable query issue in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a relatively simple variable set that seems to work out fine, but I believe it is how I am outputting it that creates an issue.

At the moment I use the following in my controller:

```
    if(empty($_GET['direction'])){
        $direction = "'LIKE', '%'";
        } else if ($_GET['direction'] === 'Inbound') {
        $direction = "'>', 1";
        } else if ($_GET['direction'] === 'Outbound'){
        $direction = "'=', 1";
    }
```

Now, I have dd'd the $direction after the fact and every test shows that it accurately chose the correct variable option given the value of $_GET['direction'].

My problem lies with how I am either outputting it there or inputting the results in the below section:

```
$manifests = DB::table('carrier_manifests')
        ->join('customers', 'carrier_manifests.carrierOrigin', '=', 'customers.id')
        ->select('carrier_manifests.*', 'customers.customer_name')  

        ->where([
                    ['manifestNumber', 'LIKE', '%' . $manifest . '%'],
                    ['originTerminal','LIKE','%' . $terminal . '%'],
                    ['carrierOrigin', $direction],
                ])
        ->orderBy('dateUnloaded', 'DESC')
        ->whereBetween('dateUnloaded', [$startDate, $endDate])
        ->limit(100)
        ->get();
```

Now, before I go on, I will say that everything works correctly here and has for some time, it's when the `carrierOrigin` and `$direction` are added that there is an issue.

For example if I leave the `direction` field empty on the page, it will set the $direction variable as equal to "'LIKE', '%'".

Unfortunately, in the where clause, this isn't sent well or something, as it returns no results, but as a test if I change the this line:

```
['carrierOrigin', $direction],
```

to

```
['carrierOrigin','LIKE','%'],
```

it returns all of the results successfully. So is there a different way I should format the output or send the output?

Comment: What you should do is pass the operator and value as separate parameters to the where in the builder, what you're doing now is saying that "LIKE %" is the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing string as second and third where arguments. Use this in controller:

```
if(empty($_GET['direction'])){
    $direction = ['LIKE', '%'];
    } else if ($_GET['direction'] === 'Inbound') {
    $direction = ['>', 1];
    } else if ($_GET['direction'] === 'Outbound'){
    $direction = ['=', 1];
}
```

Then on query:

```
$manifests = DB::table('carrier_manifests')
    ->join('customers', 'carrier_manifests.carrierOrigin', '=', 'customers.id')
    ->select('carrier_manifests.*', 'customers.customer_name')  

    ->where([
                ['manifestNumber', 'LIKE', '%' . $manifest . '%'],
                ['originTerminal','LIKE','%' . $terminal . '%'],
                ['carrierOrigin', $direction[0], $direction[1],
            ])
    ->orderBy('dateUnloaded', 'DESC')
    ->whereBetween('dateUnloaded', [$startDate, $endDate])
    ->limit(100)
    ->get();
```